# Can getString() method of ResultSet can be used for getting the value of a TEXT type column from a MySQL table?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to retrieve the value of a TEXT field from a table in a MySQL database.
MySQL version is 5.6.21
& I am using mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar

My file is given below

```
import java.sql.*;

public class DatabaseConnection {

    static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/book";

    // database credentials
    static final String USER = "username";
    static final String PASS = "password";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        try {

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);

            System.out.println("Creating statement...");
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            String query;
            query = "Select b_name, description columns from brands";
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

            while(rs.next()) {

                String first_name = rs.getString("b_name");
                String description = rs.getString("description");

                System.out.println(first_name);
                System.out.println(description);
            }

            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
            conn.close();
        } catch(SQLException se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
        } catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
            cnfe.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            //finally block used to close resources
            try{
                if(stmt!=null)
                    stmt.close();
            } catch(SQLException se2){
            }// nothing we can do
            try{
                if(conn!=null)
                    conn.close();
            } catch(SQLException se){
                se.printStackTrace();
            }//end finally try
        }//end try
        System.out.println("Goodbye!");
    }
}
```

This says that my column does not exist although I have tried this on another table, it works on VARCHAR columns but not on TEXT columns

This error shows up: [image]

But the table has a column named description: [image]

Comment: Note that MySQL Connector/J 5.1.18 is pretty old (6 years), the latest is 5.1.42. You might want to consider upgrading, see https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is NOT about the column type being text.
You can get the value of a TEXT type using `getString`.
You can verify in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-type-conversions.html).

The problem is in the query:

> ```
> query = "Select b_name, description columns from brands";
> ```

"columns" there is a mistake.
Written this way, the `description` column is in fact renamed to `columns` in your result set.
If you did `rs.getString("columns")` you would get the value.
But that's not what you want to do. You want to fix the query by dropping that word:

```
query = "Select b_name, description from brands";
```